# Incremental 65535 steps to increase LED brightness to maximum over time (in hours), stay on at maximum (for hours) and ramp down (opposite of starup)

Tags: arduino, led

Trying to understand timing / dimming and interrupts using an Arduino Uno (or any other AVR) is being made very difficult by a serious lack of example code. Having found a sketch that starts from zero and ramps up the brightness, I have tried to adapt the code to prevent the continuous loop which occurs when the 16-bit register overflows.

The attached sketch starts up from zero light output and increases over a period of time - currently using the delay() function.

Attempting to adapt the code to prevent the loop from starting the entire process again and to allow the led to remain at the "top" brightness output for x (variable) number of hours has proved to be most elusive. As one of the contributors have noted this area of coding is one of the most difficult to master.

Any advice or guidance which will put me in the right direction will be most appreciated.

...

```
//fade over 65535 steps

// 16 bit PWM on any pin
// Example uses built in LED on pin 13 (PORTB bit 5)
// https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=348170.0
void setup() {
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

  cli();                                // Disable all interrupts
  TCCR1A = 0;                           // Clear all flags in control register A
  TCCR1B = 0;                           // Clear all flags in control register B
  TCNT1 = 0;                            // Zero timer 1 count

  OCR1A = 32768;                        // Preload compare match register (50% duty cycle)

  // No prescaler
  //TCCR1B |= _BV(CS12);
  //TCCR1B |= _BV(CS11);
  TCCR1B |= _BV(CS10);

  TIMSK1 |= _BV(OCIE1A);                // Enable timer compare interrupt
  TIMSK1 |= _BV(TOIE1);                 // Enable timer overflow interrupt

  sei();                                // enable all interrupts
}

void loop() {
  for (unsigned int x = 1; x < 65535; x++) {
    //cli();
    OCR1A = x;
    //sei();
    delay(20);
  }
}

ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect) {                  // Timer1 overflow interrupt service routine
  PORTB |= _BV(PORTB5);                 // Turn LED (pin 13) on
}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) {                // Timer1 compare interrupt service routine
  PORTB &= ~_BV(PORTB5);                // Turn LED off
}
```

...

Comment: see the BlinkWithoutDelay example